# Disable javascript on page

Tags: php, javascript, include

Is there any way to disable javascript when generating a page with php?

Code:

```
<?php    
$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';    
$data = file_get_contents($url);    
$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;
echo $data;    
?>
```

Comment: Yes, but it's difficult. Plus, I'm pretty sure the owners of `kupime.com` don't approve of what you're doing

Comment: what I need to do.. include some file or???

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1673676/675590

Comment: owners of kupime.com give me approve to scraping their offers:)

Comment: something like a browser function javascript:desabled

Comment: You could just remove all script tags from the `$data` using some PHP DOM parser

Comment: I doubt you can disable javascript, because if you could then you would be able to enable it too right ? And that would be a security threat.

Comment: If they gave you permission to scour their site and scrape it, why don't they provide an API by which you can access the information?

Seems fishy to me.

Comment: they dont have API and xml is so pure

Comment: it's diffucult to explain but I need to do this - desable javascript

Comment: there is no security risk becouse I get source code with function and this is string and I finishing with they sites. Then I need to execute string like html but with javascript desabled

Comment: please visit: pluspon.com/get1.php - the only my problem is how to close,escape or something this popup window (div) to can view the content!!!

Comment: My biggest problem is that window and a way to close his...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions to remove everything that is inside `<script>` tags.

```
$text = preg_replace('/<script.+?<\/script>/im', "", $text);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do that but doesn work, I'm trying with regex, with str_replace ...

Comment: $data = str_replace ('script','',$data);

Comment: also there is a external files /script/somefile.js

Comment: please visit: http://pluspon.com/get1.php - the only my problem is how to close,escape or something this popup window (div) to can view the content!!!

Comment: Lahko poskusiš s tem: 

`$text=preg_replace('/<script.+?<\/script>/im', "", $text);`

Comment: Yes, but window is again here: pluspon.com/get1.php

Comment: my biggest problem is that window

Comment: `$text=preg_replace('/<script.+?<\/script>/im', "", $text);
$text=preg_replace('/<div id="main_window".+?<\/div>/im', "", $text);`

Comment: yes but I need this to work when I change URL also, example if i put groupon as URL things are again the same... I need somthing to close that windows to can view the content

Comment: Replace all of the urls with ones including the domain and it should work. Or you could copy contents of the ones that you need and use them,

Comment: How to replace urls ... I'm doing that right now with <base tag

Answer (score 0):

check out this **bookmarklet** that prints all script elements in a page.

```
javascript:(function(){s=document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');tx='';sr=[];for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){with(s.item(i)){t=text;if(t){tx+=t;}else{sr.push(src)};}};with(window.open()){document.write('<textarea%20id="t">'+(sr.join("\n"))+"\n\n-----\n\n"+tx+'</textarea><script%20src="http://jsbeautifier.org/beautify.js"></script><script>with(document.getElementById("t")){value=js_beautify(value);with(style){width="99%";height="99%";borderStyle="none";}};</script>');document.close();}})();
```

actually more useful would be to visit the source site http://jsbeautifier.org/